# Pandas: Each row take a string, separate by commas, and add unique word to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Sample df:

```
filldata = [['5,Blue,Football', 3], ['Baseball,Blue,College,1993', 4], ['Green,5,Football', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(filldata, columns=['Tags', 'Count'])
```

I am wanting a unique list of words used in the `Tags` column. So I'm trying to loop through df and pull each row of `Tags`, split on `,` and add the words to a list. I could either check and add only unique words, or add them all and then just pull unique. I would like a solution for both methods if possible to see which is faster.
So expected output should be:

`5, Blue, Football, Baseball, College, 1993, Green`.

I have tried these:

```
tagslist = df['Tags'][0].split(',')  # To give me initial starting words
def adduniquetags(newtags, tagslist):
    thesetags = newtags.split(',')
    tagslist = tagslist.extend(thesetags)
    return tagslist
tagslist = [adduniquetags(row, tagslist) for row in df['Tags']]
```

and

```
tagslist = df['Tags'][0].split(',')
def adduniquetags(newtags, tagslist):
    thesetags = newtags.split(',')
    for word in thesetags:
            if word not in tagslist:
                tagslist.append(word)   
tagslist = [adduniquetags(row, tagslist) for row in df['Tags']]
```

These two are essentially the same with one looking only for unique words. Both of these return a list of 'None'.
I have also tried this:

```
tagslist = df['Tags'][0].split(',')
def adduniquetags(newtags, tagslist):
    thesetags = newtags.split(',')
    tagslist = list(set(tagslist + thesetags))
    return tagslist
tagslist = [adduniquetags(row, tagslist) for row in df['Tags']]
```

This one is adding unique values for each row, but not the words in each row. So even though I tried to split on the `,`, it is still treating the entire text as one instead of using the individual words from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split strings, then use [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to horizontally stack all the lists in column `Tags`, next use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on this stacked array, to find the unique elements in array.

```
lst = np.unique(np.hstack(df['Tags'].str.split(','))).tolist()
```

Another possible idea using [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
lst = df['Tags'].str.split(',').explode().unique().tolist()
```

Result:

```
['1993', '5', 'Baseball', 'Blue', 'College', 'Football', 'Green']
```